# I want to create form fields in Django views.py rather then forms.py

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I am creating my form in Form.py like this:

```
class pdftabelModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = pdftabel_tool_
        fields = ['apn', 'owner_name']
    apn = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= Field.objects.values_list('name', flat=True), empty_label="(Choose field)")
    owner_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= Field.objects.values_list('name', flat=True), empty_label="(Choose field)")
```

But due to some reasons like 'self' is not available in form.py. I can only access it in views.py. So I want to make it like

```
   class FieldForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = pdftabel_tool_
        fields = (
            'apn',
            'owner_name',)
```

How can I make these fields as dropdown like I did in my forms.py?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you set on doing it in views.py? forms.py is the appropriate place to do this.

Instead of redefining your fields, you should use the form's `__init__` method to override the querysets for your fields, like so:

```
class pdftabelModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = pdftabel_tool_
        fields = ['apn', 'owner_name']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(pdftabelModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['apn'].queryset = X
        self.fields['owner_name'].queryset = X
```

EDIT: if you need to pass extra parameters to your form, update the init method to this:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.layer_id = self.kwargs.pop('layer_id')
        super(pdftabelModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['apn'].queryset = X
        self.fields['owner_name'].queryset = X
```

And when you initialize your form from views.py, pass the parameter:

```
form = pdftableModelForm(layer_id=X)
```

Comment: actually I am getting a  self.layer_id in my view.py. I want to filter values like "(queryset= Field.objects.filters(map_id=self.layer_id)values_list('name', flat=True)",

Comment: See this question for how to pass extra parameters to forms: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660037/django-forms-pass-parameter-to-form .

Comment: Oh right . But after analyzing, I came to know 'self' in this form.py is different from  'form' in that view.py . So now I must have to just make filed here and assign drop drown query in view.py ? Can you guide in this please?