# my Django form not validating when using __init__ for a dynamic Radio field

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have written a form which has a Radio Button, whose values I provide when I initialize the form. The form is being displayed perfectly but when I need to use the values submitted through the form, I cannot, because it is not validating.

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class voteForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self,candidates, *args, **kwargs):
        super(voteForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Candidate'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=candidates, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from register.models import Candidate, Voter
from voting.models import Vote
from voting.forms import voteForm
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    context={}
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = voteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # do something with data
            return HttpResponse('Success')
    voterid=1
    context['voter']=Voter.objects.get(id=voterid)
    request.session['id']=voterid
    candidates=Candidate.objects.filter(region=context['voter'].region).values_list('id','name')
    form = voteForm(candidates)
    context['form']=form
    return render(request,'voting/index.html',context)
```

Edit.

HTML code

```html
<h1>Vote</h1>
{{ voter.name }}
{{ voter.region }}
<form action="/vote/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.as_p }}
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the **candidates** choicelist that you are passing to the form during creation. The method you've used here is not appropriate and that's why the form can't get the choicelist and thus fails to validate.
You have 2 options here. You can either define the **candidates** choicelist inside the **forms.py** and use it or use proper method to pass **candidates** choicelist to the form.

**Option 1:**

In **forms.py** :

```
     # dummy candidates list
    candidates = [
        (Male, 'Male'),
        (Female, 'Female'),
    ]


    class VoteForm(forms.Form):
        fields = ('Candidate')

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(VoteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

            self.fields['Candidate'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=candidates, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

And in **views.py** just remove the candidates parameter from VoteForm() method.

**Option 2**:

There is already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660037/django-forms-pass-parameter-to-form). You can check that out.

I have tested **Option 1** and it works correctly.

Comment: But I don't want to link the form with the model, I simply want to use the value submitted by the user. Anyway I did try your method, didn't work.

Comment: Ok, I am testing this.

Comment: I have updated my answer . Please inform me if you solve the problem.