# Populate form data in CreateView with get_initial() from model

Tags: django

I want a create form where people can select "a template" which prepoulate the form. The template is another model with the same fields.
For example i have an AbstractArticle and TemplateArticle and RealArticle with the same structure.

I am trying to use get_initial() to polulate the form but it takes only a dict and it is odd, because the form is quite complex (I can't get it to work with dropdown).

Is there a way to supply a model instance as initial data?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your actual code and what you tried I'm a bit lost, but maybe this post [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14660051/9813380) is what you are looking for. Doing a bit of changes on that answer I can give you this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    initial = super(MyFormView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.temp_mod = kwargs.pop('template_model_id')
    template_model = TemplateModel.objects.get(id=temp_mod)
    # update initial field defaults with custom set default values:
    initial.update(
        {'field1': template_model.data1, 
         'field2': template_model.data2})
    return initial
```

*Not tested*

The idea here is get the template model id from the kwargs, get the object and then fill the information in the initial.update to the correspondant fields.

Comment: I did something like that but when updating initial I am unable to get it working for dropdown list and multiple select box

Comment: without looking at the code I cannot helo much more, please edit your question adding the code